# find cell value after matching for row number and column number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to find which user is "P" given a date in data below.

I've tried retrieving the row number of the given date using "=MATCH(A5,$A$4:$A$5,0)"
and also the column number of "P", using "=MATCH("P",B5:G5,0)"

I'm unsure how to bring them together to get the desired output.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Nested `INDEX/MATCH`

[image]

```
=IFNA(INDEX($B$1:$G$1,1,MATCH($J2,INDEX($B$2:$G$3,MATCH($I2,$A$2:$A$3,0),0),0)),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new column H where H4 has a formula of `=INDEX(B$3:G$3,MATCH("P",B4:G4,0)`.

Then your second table's second column formula can be `=INDEX(H$4:H$5, MATCH(yourDateCellHere,  A$4:A$5,0))` because a lot of the heavy lifting is already done in the first table.

Then, if you wish, hide your new column H.